# How to install pthread on php 5.4 on an x64 windows architecture?

Tags: php, pthreads

The dll founded here : 
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/

contain a x64 version only for php 5.5.

Comment: Build it from source ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used easyPhp 13.1 vc11, it's not x64 but the php5.5 version works great with the x86 phtread dll.

Answer (score 1):

PHP only started distributing x64 binaries with the 5.5 series of releases, for an x86 build before that you are pretty much on your own ...

Hint: apache friends is a good place to look for builds of PHP and the apache/php stack in general, someone is bound to have what you are looking for ...